# Angular 2 Custom Validation Service Provider

Tags: forms, angular, validation

I have defined few custom validators for my forms and everything is working fine. I am confused whether these validators need to be added as providers in the module?

Everything is working a expected without adding as well, it just that i seek a conceptual understanding for the same. Any guidance would be appreciated along with the concept behind it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular 2 [documentation on custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) uses two approaches, a function for reactive forms and a `Directive` for template driven forms.

When using the reactive forms approach the function doesn't need to be provided.

When using template driven forms, with a `Directive`, the `Directive` will need to be declared in a module.